# String equals printing false in apparently equal strings (encoding)

Tags: html, string, jsf, jsf-2

Inside of `programacao.getNome()` there is the string `457P D (0)    NOVA PROG`
and inside of the string `nome` there is `457PÂ DÂ (0)Â Â Â Â NOVAÂ PROG`.

It's the same string with different encoding so when I run
`programacao.getNome().equals(nome))` the result is `false`.

With `programacao.getNome().getBytes()`
 the result is

`[52, 53, 55, 80, 32, 68, 32, 40, 48, 41, 32, 32, 32, 32, 78, 79, 86, 65, 32, 80, 82, 79, 71]` and with nome.getBytes the result is

`[52, 53, 55, 80, -62, -96, 68, -62, -96, 40, 48, 41, -62, -96, -62, -96, -62, -96, -62, -96, 78, 79, 86, 65, -62, -96, 80, 82, 79, 71]`.

The difference is programação.getNome() is coming from a field in the database ( mysql ) and the parameter `nome` is coming from the xhtml page in JSF through the method `getAsObject` in a class the implements the interface `Converter`.

We had to replace `" "` with `&nbsp` before sending it to the selectOneMenu so it would display with the spaces, but when selecting the item in the dropdown the string comes to the managed bean this way.

At the top of the `xhtml` we put `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`, so maybe that's the problem? Where should I start to look?

Comment: Don't use `getBytes()` to determine the difference. Dump the contents as UTF-16 code units. Something like: `for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { log((int) text.charAt(i); }`. Then you can see what the data *really* is. Fundamentally though, it looks like `nome` really doesn't start with "0028" at all... it looks like it starts with "457P". The rest depends on the default encoding on your machine...

Comment: I edited the question because I had made mistakes. Also here is the result of the code you sent me:
nome.charAt(i) :
52 53 55 80 32 68 32 40 48 41 32 32 32 32 78 79 86 65 32 80 82 79 71
-----------------------------
programacao.getNome().charAt(i):
52 53 55 80 194 160 68 194 160 40 48 41 194 160 194 160 194 160 194 160 78 79 86 65 194 160 80 82 79 71

Comment: Well look - the two strings clearly aren't the same. Look at character 5 in each string, for example. 194 isn't the same as 32. I also suspect that you should actually be specifying UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1...

Answer (score -1):

Per the definition of String.equals(java.lang.Object):

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

I am assuming you are using java.lang.String, so the problem is that the two sequences of characters are not equal.

Per java.lang.String documentation:

> A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format

So your problem is that you are putting two different encodings into a String, which ends up as UTF-16. You will want to convert your character sequences to UTF-16 before putting it into a String.